# jQuery simple function is not working

Tags: jquery, html

HTML code:

```js
    $('.alertme').click(function(){
        alert('By selecting new image your old image will be remove');
        $(this).removeClass('alertme');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
#Before a Function is executed
    <input type="file" name="efile" id="efile" style="width:100%" class="alertme">
    #After a function is executed
    <input type="file" name="efile" id="efile" style="width:100%" class="">
```

it still alerting me after an executing function. I didn't know why It happening? can you please help me? your help is appreciated.

Comment: No duplicate IDs!

Comment: @Andrew Li My function is based on class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing  class doesn't remove the attached event handler.Remove the event handler by using [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method.

```
$('.alertme').click(function(){
    alert('By selecting new image your old image will be remove');
    $(this).off('click').removeClass('alertme');
});
```

Comment: @RushabhShah : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Traverse again for check whether the dom element or class is removed or not Using through event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', '.alertme', function(){
    alert('By selecting new image your old image will be remove');
    $(this).removeClass('alertme');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

```
$('.alertme').one('click', function(){
    alert('By selecting new image your old image will be remove');
    $(this).removeClass('alertme');
});
```

However better option would be to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).

```
$(document).on('click', '.alertme', function(){
    alert('By selecting new image your old image will be remove');
    $(this).removeClass('alertme');
});
```